# Not able to click on a button, when isExisting is true; isDisplayedInViewport true, but waitForDisplayed timed out for the element in WebdriverIO

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, mocha.js, webdriver-io

The script fails with this error.
Error: element (".WONDERESC") still not displayed after 30000ms

Tried different combinations for Xpath, (relative, fixed, text()} and CSS selectors, but the button not clicked. The **sign-in button** div in the code block:

```
<div>
    <div class="WONDERBSC" role="form">
        <div>
            <div class="WONDERJ1B" data-automation-id="userName">
                <div class="TOM-Label WONDERP1B"
                    title="Username">Username</div>
                <input type="text"
                        class="TOM-TextBox WONDERM1B" aria-label="Username">
                    <button type="button" class="TOM-Button WONDERN1B"/>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div>
                <div class="WONDERJ1B"
                    data-automation-id="password">
                    <div class="TOM-Label WONDERP1B" title="Password">Password</div>
                    <input type="password" class="TOM-PasswordTextBox WONDERM1B" aria-label="Password">
                        <button type="button" class="TOM-Button WONDERN1B"/>
                </div>
            </div>
                <button type="button"
                        class="WONDERESC"
                        data-automation-id="goButton">Sign In</button>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Kindly suggest the workarounds - the other conditions are also meeting- visibility-true, display-block, opacity not zero.

Thanks,
Tan

Comment: Please share your code. Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ChristianBaumann
Thanks for the suggestions- edited the question. For Code - you want to see the xpath- css selectors tried?

Comment: Please share the website where it is happening. If yours is private then a similar one.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeG. for the response, - the HTML code block is already shared.
also there is no change in the HTML when page loads with automation script. And I have verified the selector correctly and uniquely identified the element when script stops (by adding 60s delay).

Comment: The HTML block is not a page. There might be some issues with styles, js and so on. It's not enough.

Comment: @MikeG.
please see the sign-in button for the issue:
https://impl.workday.com/wday/authgwy/accenture_dpt2/login.htmld?redirect=n
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If element is not displayed then you have to make it visible

**Case 1**
The element takes some time to be visible automatically
In this case, you can use webdriver wait
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xxxx"));

**Case 2**
Element is visible after some interaction like mouse movement or click or type
Then you have to perform that action with selenium. For mouse movements you can use action classes

Comment: Thanks, @rahul, for suggestions. The given suggestions do not work on the ui.

Answer (score 0):

As it was told in the comments, you are using invalid selectors.

Assuming you have the latest WebdriverIO v6, the following works like a charm

```js
// open page
browser.url('https://impl.workday.com/wday/authgwy/accenture_dpt2/login.htmld?redirect=n')

const form = $('[data-automation-id="authPanel"] [role="form"]')
// make sure form is visible
expect(form).toBeVisible()

// define form data
const formData = [{
    id: 'userName', value: 'test'
}, {
    id: 'password', value: 'password'
}]

// fill form
formData.forEach(f => {
    form.$(`[data-automation-id="${f.id}"] input`).setValue(f.value)
})

// submit form
form.$('button[data-automation-id="goButton"]').click()

// make sure error message exist
const errorMessage = $('[data-automation-id="alertMessage"]')
expect(errorMessage).toBeVisible()
expect(errorMessage).toHaveTextContaining('Invalid user name or password')
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer with the code. It works fine in wdIO-6, even the selectors I used.
The issue is with wdIO5, which I use. - this does not work $('button[data-automation-id="goButton"]').click(). 
Thanks.